# Why won't my image rotate when pressing the arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, animation, web-applications, addeventlistener, keydown

I made a web app where you can control the movement an image of robot floor cleaner by using the arrow keys on the keyboard. On [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kynants/jrzma4sp/3/), it works just fine. On my local machine using Google Chrome, Firefox, and Edge; the image moves, but I can't figure out why it's not rotating. Is anyone able to duplicate this problem and solve it on their local machine?

```js
let angle = 0,
    img = document.getElementById('robot');

function leftArrowPressed() {
  let element = document.getElementById("robot");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 20 + 'px';
  angle = 270;
  img.className = "rotate"+angle;
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
  let element = document.getElementById("robot");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 20 + 'px';
  angle = 90;
  img.className = "rotate"+angle;
}

function upArrowPressed() {
  let element = document.getElementById("robot");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 20 + 'px';
  angle = 0;
  img.className = "rotate"+angle;
}

function downArrowPressed() {
  let element = document.getElementById("robot");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 20 + 'px';
  angle = 180;
  img.className = "rotate"+angle;
}

function moveSelection(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 39:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 38:
      upArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 40:
      downArrowPressed();
      break;
  }
}

function docReady() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://github.com/kynants/RobotFloorCleaner/blob/master/floor.jpg?raw=true");
}

/*Floor cleaner will not move unless styling is applied inline rather than from imported stylesheet file*/
/*#robot {*/
/*  height: 15px;*/
/*  width: 15px;*/
/*  position: absolute;*/
/*  left: 0;*/
/*  top: 0;*/
/*}*/

#robot {
  transform-origin: top left; /* IE 10+, Firefox, etc. */
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left; /* Chrome */
  -ms-transform-origin: top left; /* IE 9 */
}
#robot.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#robot.rotate180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%,-100%);
}
#robot.rotate270 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Robot Floor Cleaner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="move.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="">
  <!-- Floor cleaner will not move unless styling is applied inline rather than from imported stylesheet file -->
  <img src="https://github.com/kynants/RobotFloorCleaner/blob/master/robot.png?raw=true" id="robot" alt="robot floor cleaner" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" width="15%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The JSFiddle link is missing.

Comment: You need to share your code or at least describe how are you rotating the images.

Comment: You have the `rotate.js` script commented out in your html.

Comment: That's an old file I commented out for now instead of removing it since I was not sure if I needed it later depending on what the issue was. At this point, I'll remove it.

Comment: This is good stuff, even o the fiddle, its not rotating

Comment: The snippet here on Stack Overflow does not contain the commented out line on JSfiddle. That prevents rotating. And also, all code on stack overflow does not contain logic to rotate. The robot is moving and looking in the moving direction for me. Though not rotating as there is no code that says so. Please add the missing code.